# Insert datetime in column automatically

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is is possible to insert the datetime in the table just like how a primary key would do?

I have a table name `sales`. In `sales` table, there is a `Date` column where the date should be stored in this format : `d-m-Y H:i:s`. How do I do that?
How do I add it here:

```
while($row_boat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_join)){
    $sales_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
    $sales_itemid = $row_boat['ItemId'];
    $sales_itemprice = $row_boat['ItemPrice'];
    $sales_qty = $row_boat['qty'];
    $sales_total = $sales_itemprice * $sales_qty;

    $insert_sales = "
        insert into sales
        (customer_email, ItemId, ItemPrice, Quantity, Total)
        values ('$sales_email', '$sales_itemid', '$sales_itemprice', '$sales_qty', '$sales_total')
    ";

    $run_sales = mysqli_query($con, $insert_sales);
}
```

Comment: Q: Why would you want to store datetime like that? You're just making your life difficult and will be even more so later on. MySQL has built-in functions made just for it. However and to answer this, you will need to store that as varchar but will then need to use strtotime() later on. DATETIME is stored as YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00 as an FYI in MySQL. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: just set the column to `default: NOW()` to get the current date automatically added

Comment: Use current time stamp auto update and change yur format as per mysql